# Template function is used instead of typed

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class Foo {
    public:
    Foo(){};

    template<typename T>
    Foo (T&) {
        std::cout << "template" << std::endl;
    }

    Foo(Foo&) {
        std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;
    }

    Foo(const Foo&) {
        std::cout << "copy2" << std::endl;
    }
};


int main(){
    Foo f;

    Foo f2 (f);

}
```

It prints "copy", which is correct.

However if I remove the `Foo(Foo&)`:

```
class Foo {
    public:
    Foo(){};

    template<typename T>
    Foo (T&) {
        std::cout << "template" << std::endl;
    }

    //Foo(Foo&) {
    //    std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;
    //}

    Foo(const Foo&) {
        std::cout << "copy2" << std::endl;
    }
};


int main(){
    Foo f;

    Foo f2 (f);

}
```

it prints "template". I expected it to print "copy2" because it is typed parameters. Why is it using template instead?

Comment: I think STL covered this scenario quite well in his Overload Resolution video on Channel 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to perform overload resolution, the compiler needs to evaluate the constructor template using template argument deduction. So it creates a constructor like this:

```
template<>
Foo<Foo>::Foo(Foo&);
```

This constructor takes an lvalue reference to *non-const*, as oppose to the non-template constructor. This is preferred because an identity conversion (i.e no conversion) is preferred over a qualification conversion.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Foo f;
```

`f` is not a `const` object of `Foo`. So its type match to following function and it will print **template**.

```
template<typename T>
    Foo (T&) {
        std::cout << "template" << std::endl;
    }
```

If you define f as follows, it will print as you expected.

```
const  Foo f;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the same reason that your first code sample doesn't print `copy2`. The `f` you are referencing is not `const`, so the compiler first tries non-const references. Overload matching matches `template<typename T=Foo> Foo(T&)` giving an exact match while `Foo(const Foo&)` requires a cv-adjustment of the parameter being passed.

Try the following:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
    public:
    Foo(){};

    template<typename T>
    Foo (T&) {
        std::cout << "template" << std::endl;
    }

    //Foo(Foo&) {
    //    std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;
    //}

    Foo(const Foo&) {
        std::cout << "copy2" << std::endl;
    }
};


int main(){
    const Foo f;

    Foo f2 (f);

}
```

http://ideone.com/zOf1qX